Spring Security 6 - how to handle InvalidBearerTokenExeption

Spring boot 3

Spring Security 6

what wrong i am doing ?


Defined ExceptionHandler
@ExceptionHandler({AuthenticationException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidBearerToken(AuthenticationException exception) {
        Error error = new Error().errorCode(Error.ErrorCodeEnum.INVALID_DATE_RANGE)
            .errorDescription(exception.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(error, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

@ExceptionHandler({InvalidBearerTokenException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidBearerToken(InvalidBearerTokenException exception) {
        Error error = new Error().errorCode(Error.ErrorCodeEnum.INVALID_DATE_RANGE)
            .errorDescription(exception.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(error, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }


Security Chain*
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/v1/**"))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
            .exceptionHandling(ex-> ex.accessDeniedPage("/localhost")); // Some random url
        return http.build();
    }


@ExceptionHandler({AuthenticationException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidBearerToken(AuthenticationException exception) {
        Error error = new Error().errorCode(Error.ErrorCodeEnum.INVALID_DATE_RANGE)
            .errorDescription(exception.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(error, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

2024-07-04T16:58:27.093+05:30 TRACE 953112 --- [Alpha-Project] [nio-8081-exec-1] .s.r.w.a.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Failed to process authentication request

org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.InvalidBearerTokenException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Jwt expired at 2024-07-02T17:36:11Z
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:88)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ObservationAuthenticationManager.lambda$authenticate$1(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:54)
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:565)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ObservationAuthenticationManager.authenticate(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224)
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:904)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtValidationException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Jwt expired at 2024-07-02T17:36:11Z
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.validateJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:193)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:139)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:99)
    ... 85 common frames omitted


Returning Custom Error Message to Caller
Guide to Spring Security Exception Handling

Even if you handle error in authenticationEntryPoint - like throwing exception - it does not come to exception handler.
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtValidationException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Jwt expired at 2024-07-02T17:36:11Z
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.validateJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:193)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:139)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:99)
    ... 85 common frames omitted

2024-07-05T06:15:45.712+05:30 TRACE 1451121 --- [Acme] [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@4d8dc19b
2024-07-05T06:15:45.712+05:30 TRACE 1451121 --- [Acme] [nio-8081-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 2 matching mappings: [{ [/error]}, { [/error], produces [text/html]}]

2024-07-05T06:15:45.712+05:30 TRACE 1451121 --- [Acme] [nio-8081-exec-4] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@4d8dc19b
2024-07-05T06:15:45.712+05:30 TRACE 1451121 --- [Acme] [nio-8081-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 2 matching mappings: [{ [/error]}, { [/error], produces [text/html]}]


you can add an authenticationEntryPoint as below
   @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/v1/**"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()).authenticationEntryPoint(((request, response, authException) -> {
                    if (authException instanceof InvalidBearerTokenException){
                        //do something
                    }
                })))
                .exceptionHandling(ex-> ex.accessDeniedPage("/localhost")); // Some random url
        return http.build();
    }


does not solve - even if an exception is thrown - or set response within - it still does not go to ExceptionHandler -- I have added exception

So solved the issue -- response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
Error error = new Error().errorCode(Error.ErrorCodeEnum.UNAUTHORIZED)
.errorDescription(authException.getMessage());
response.getWriter().write(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(error)); --

Exceptions thrown in the filter will not be handled by the exception handler annotated with @ExceptionHandler,Only use authenticationEntryPoint
